# duda referente a codigo c++

Tags: dev-c++

hola he visto frecuentemente esta linea de código en varios programas de ejemplo pero desconozco su función, alguien pudiera decirme cual es?

La linea en cuestión es

**proc(a,b)**

aca el codigo completo

```
 #include<stdio.h> 
 #include <cmath>

void proc(float a,float b){

    scanf("%f",&a);

    b = pow(a,3);

    printf("\n \n El cubo del numero ingresado es: %.2f",b);

}

int main(){

    float a,b;
    printf("\n Ingrese un numero: \n \n");
    proc(a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: proc(a,b) lo estás definiendo en el codigo que mostrás . void proc(float a,float b) .. Y lo que hace esa función es la potencia de un número.

Comment: El código que muestras es 'c', no 'c++' (aunque funciona en 'c++'), simplemente invocas la función que habías definido arriba pasándo los valores de `a` y `b` (pero a  `a` el valor se lo das dentro del método y nunca defines el valor de `b`).

Answer (score 0):

`proc(a,b)`es tu llamada a la función que tienes definida mas arriba, afuera del main. En esa misma función ingresas los dos parámetros con los cuales se realiza una potencia y termina mostrándolos por pantalla.

Un ultimo apunte esto es C no C++

Espero que te haya ayudado